# how to display people data in the body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

Hi guys trying to make an mini application in react JS , in that application i want to display data in the my body part when i  do search on my textbar , so anyone tell me how can i do it or what should i do to display data?

> App.js This is my main component

```
import './App.css';
import Star from './Star';
import People from './People';
import Planet from './Planet';

function App(props) {

  const {people,planet} = props;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Star />
      <People data={people}/>
      <Planet data={planet}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Star.js
> This is my star component where i fetch my all star war apis

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Star.css';

const Star = () => {

    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
    const [planet, setPlanet] = useState([]);

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (search === "") {
            alert("please Enter some value");
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchPeople() {
            let result = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/?format=json");
            let data = await result.json();
            setPeople(data.results);
        }

        async function fetchPlanet() {
            let result = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?format=json");
            let data = await result.json();
            setPlanet(data.results);
        }

        fetchPeople();
        fetchPlanet();
    }, [])

    console.log("people", people);
    console.log("planet", planet);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className='container'>
                <h2>Star War</h2>
                <div className='jumbotron'>
                    <input type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder='Search...'
                        value={search}
                        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span><button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={onSubmit}>Search</button></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Star;
```

> people.js

This is my people that i want to display in the my body part

```
import React from 'react';

const People = (props) => {
    const { data } = props;

    return (
        <div className="row">
            {data && data.map((people, i) => {
                return (
                    <div className="col-md-3" key={i}>
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h4>{people.name}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default People;
```

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve ? what did you try ?

Comment: i want to display peoples information

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your issue, you want to display the *People* component and the issue is how to pass it the data fetched in the *Star* component.

The solution is to move the state of the data in the parent component so that it can be passed easily to all its children.

```
function App(props) {

  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  const [planet, setPlanet] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPeople() {
        let result = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/?format=json");
        let data = await result.json();
        setPeople(data.results);
    }

    async function fetchPlanet() {
        let result = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?format=json");
        let data = await result.json();
        setPlanet(data.results);
    }

    fetchPeople();
    fetchPlanet();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Star
        people={people} //if you need these in the Star component
        planet={planet} //if you need these in the Star component
      />
      <People data={people}/>
      <Planet data={planet}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```